# Bluetooth audio player commands

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth, avaudioplayer

I am developing an app using React Native with an audio player in it. I am trying to find out how to listen for Bluetooth audio commands like Play, Pause, Stop, Skip forward, Skip back. All of these work with other audio playing apps. But I cannot find out how to listen for these. I suspect it is different in IoS and Android so I need to know how to listen for them in both. I seem to be looking in all the wrong places because I haven't found a single thing about how to do it. Pointing me in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: You could see how this library does it: https://github.com/doublesymmetry/react-native-track-player

Comment: Yes - that did the trick. I needed to complete replace the Audio library from expo and change to a development build to use the native code but after all that work, it kind of works. What it does wrong (IMHO) is that the Remote Events have too much smarts in them. Apparently the RemoteNext does get triggered if there is only one Track in the queue. They should just send me the events and let me handle what I do with them. But overall, though quirky, it has done the trick that I could not have done. Thanks.